# Фильтр по датам, еще одному условию dataframe

Tags: pandas

Есть dataframe:

Загружаю файл, делаю индексом одну из колонок. Колонок всего 7. Необходимо схлопнуть по "СубконтоДт1" и при этом отфильтровать по дате и поставщику.

Ниже привожу пример, что должно получиться.

```
                 Дата           Поставщик       Цена
СубконтоДт1      
перчатки         12.01.12       ООО"А"          12.00
перчатки         13.01.12       ООО"А"          14.00
профиль          26.02.14       ООО"В"          26.00
профиль          29.03.14       ООО"В"          27.00
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

Вот так примерно выглядит сейчас таблица:

```
df = pd.read_csv("333.csv", sep=';', header=0, index_col="СубконтоДт1", decimal=',')

                 Дата           Поставщик       Цена
СубконтоДт1      
перчатки         12.01.12       ООО"А"          12.00
уголок           14.01.12       ООО"С"           5.00
профиль          26.02.14       ООО"В"          26.00
перчатки         13.01.12       ООО"А"          14.00
профиль          29.03.14       ООО"В"          27.00
```

> И так далее , много разной номенклатуры от разных поставщиков за разные даты

Comment: все ответы оценивал. Сайт пишет, что голос учтен, но из-за рейтинга не отображается

Comment: И как я могу не оценивать ответ , если мне тут очень сильно помогают?

Comment: Уже всё в порядке. Ваша таблица чуть чудесная — даты не выглядят как даты, в поставщиках кавычки, в ценах запятые. В первую очередь сделайте `df.dtypes` (или `print(df.dtypes)`) чтобы проверить типы индивидуальных столбцов.

Comment: это схематичное отображение. При про проверке Дата - datetime64[ns], Цена - float64

Comment: Можете привести припер ожидаемого результата, лучше всего прямо дополнением вашего вопроса?

Comment: Эта таблица - это как должно выглядеть. Я сейчас покажу как она сейчас выглядит.

Comment: Не понял — верхняя таблица, это результат, и  в нижней оригинальные значения? Вы хотите только сортировать строки таблицы, или в результате будет менее / более строк?

Comment: Да, верхняя таблица - это результат. Нижняя это как она выглядит сейчас.  В реальности гораздо больше строк. Хотел сделать проще пример для восприятия (похоже не очень получилось). В СубконтоДт1 много разных номенклатур. Условно говоря сотня разных материалов, которые периодически докупают. Хотел бы отсортировать их по датам и поставщикам.

Comment: Значит, вы хотите только сортировать для 3 ключей — СубконтоДт1, Дата и Поставщик? Все 3 регулярными столбцами, или какой-то из них индексом?

Comment: Индексом: СубконтоДт1. + Дата и Поставщик

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df_result = df.reset_index().sort_values(["СубконтоДт1", "Дата", "Поставщик"]).set_index("СубконтоДт1")
```

---

*Объяснение:*

- Сначала сделаем из индекса `СубконтоДт1` регулярный столбец
  (`.reset_index()`),
- затем сделаем сортировку для 3 столбцов
  (`.sort_values(["СубконтоДт1", "Дата", "Поставщик"])`)
- наконец сделаем столбец `СубконтоДт1` опять индексом
  (`.set_index("СубконтоДт1")`).